# Best algorithm to strip leading and trailing spaces in C

Tags: c, string, trim

What is the best approach in stripping leading and trailing spaces in C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this entirely in place.

```
 void stripLeadingAndTrailingSpaces(char* string){

     assert(string);

     /* First remove leading spaces */

     const char* firstNonSpace = string;

     while(*firstNonSpace != '\0' && isspace(*firstNonSpace))
     {
          ++firstNonSpace;
     }

     size_t len = strlen(firstNonSpace)+1;         

     memmove(string, firstNonSpace, len);

     /* Now remove trailing spaces */

     char* endOfString = string + len;

     while(string < endOfString  && isspace(*endOfString))
     {
          --endOfString ;
     }

     *endOfString = '\0';

}
```

Comment: There are two problems with this: (1) strcpy has undefined behaviour if the source and destination buffers overlap (use memmove or a while loop to copy the string), and (2) consider what happens if the string contains embedded whitespace characters, not just leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: I don't really like the use of assert here. In my mind, assert means 'this _really_ shouldn't happen, but just in case', whereas a null pointer passed to this function is quite possible. Perhaps it is merely taste.

Comment: My interpretation is this: A string which consists of one or more printable characters is of course a string. An empty string (containing only the null terminator) is also a string. However, a string which is just a null pointer is not a string at all; this is a precondition violation.

Comment: I would like to see this calculate the size that actually NEEDS to be memmoved rather than memmoving the whole string and then trimming the trailing spaces.

Comment: @eben: One could argue that NULL pointers are so common that you have the wrong precondition. I would put the test for NULL inside the function otherwise you are forcing all users of your function to test for NULL. Do users to always do this:  if (x) {stripLeadingAndTrailingSpaces(x);}

Comment: isspace('\0') is not TRUE. Check your algorithm actually strips the back space.

Comment: If the string is all blank, this code does 'strlen()' from the first character after the trailing '\0'.  The result is unlikely to be satisfactory!

Comment: It would also be more efficient if you worked out where the last non-space character is before you did the memmove() - there is not much point in copying the trailing spaces if you are then going to hide them after a NUL '\0'.

Comment: Any solution eliciting this much commentary is not a strong solution.

Comment: I've never seen an accepted answer with negative votes before.

Comment: i also think that this is wrong: char* endOfString = string + len;  you will point exactly at the terminating, new null character. which is of course not a space, and your loop immediately terminates.

Comment: anyway, i agree with the guy with assert, would use it myself too. that NULL pointers are common is not a good argument IMHO. that makes them not valid arguments or valid strings.

Comment: i think this statement char* endOfString = string + len is really wrong because you indexed the string out of bound, consider "abc",then according to your algorithm,len is 4,then string+4 is absolutely exception.

Comment: I have to down-vote this.  As my newly added [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45620263) shows, the code on display here (as of 2017-08-09) neither strips the trailing blanks nor properly respects the bounds of the array if the input string is empty — consists of a single null byte `'\0'`.  The necessary changes are simple, but they are necessary.  The Linux code in [tuminoid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40657/tuminoid)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/352109) is OK, though the semantics are different.

Answer (score 24):

Here is how linux kernel does the trimming, called strstrip():

```
char *strstrip(char *s)
{
    size_t size;
    char *end;

    size = strlen(s);

    if (!size)
        return s;

    end = s + size - 1;
    while (end >= s && isspace(*end))
        end--;
    *(end + 1) = '\0';

    while (*s && isspace(*s))
        s++;

    return s;
}
```

Its basically a better formatted and error-checked version what the previous poster said.

Comment: This implementation is easy to misuse. A naive user is likely to try to free the returned pointer (or overwrite their original pointer). Since we're not working in the kernel, I think it would be nicer to copy the trimmed string to the beginning of the buffer :)

Comment: This looks quite bad. You're not only altering the original string but creating another pointer at a different location; I'd say this is a bad example at this level; I also agree that a buffer should be passed, or the result stored somewhere else.

Comment: ...If you don't keep the original pointer; surely you've just caused a memory leak as the initial "space" can never be recovered.

Comment: This discussion shows that what makes a good answer depends on the context in which the code will be used.  If preserving the original string is important, this is not the solution; otherwise, this works.  It also works unless tracking the initial pointer is important or a memory copy is an issue,

Comment: To address the concerns listed in the comments, you could just return strdup(s) and require the caller free the result. (i know non-standard but it's like 4 lines to hand roll if you don't have it).

Comment: @widgisoft: you aren't losing the original pointer, it isn't passed by "reference" or anything. you could easily do this safely. char *const s = strpdup(" hello world"); char *const s2 = strstrip(s); /* use s2 */ free(s);

Answer (score 9):

This question looks as if it might be a homework question, so I'll answer obliquely: look up the man pages for isspace(3) and strlen(3) and use pointer arithmetic.  Also depending on the problem at hand you may need malloc(3) to hold space for the result.

Don't forget that the representation of a C string includes a trailing 0 byte, often written '\0', which is not counted as part of the length of the string.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a version using isspace:

```
char * trim(char *c) {
    char * e = c + strlen(c) - 1;
    while(*c && isspace(*c)) c++;
    while(e > c && isspace(*e)) *e-- = '\0';
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
char *strstrip(char *s)
{
    char *end;

    while ( (*s) && isspace( *s))
        s++;

    if(!( *s) )
        return s;
    end = s;

    while( ! *end)
        end++;
    end--;

    while (end ! = s && isspace( *end))
        end--;
    *(end + 1) = '\0';

    return s;
}
```

It is basically a more optimized code (in terms of speed & codesize ).

If we need to retain memory space then,

```
void strstrip(char *s)
{
    char *start;
    char *end;

    start = s; 
    while ( (*start) && isspace( *start))
        start++;

    if(!( *start) ) 
    {
        *s='\0';
        return ;
    }
    end = start;

    while( ! *end)
        end++;
    end--;

    while (end ! = start && isspace( *end))
        end--;
    *(end + 1) = '\0';

    memmove(s, start, end-start+1);

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more concise and safer version of lakshmanaraj's first function:

```
#include <ctype.h>
char *mytrim(char *s)
{
    if(s) { /* Don't forget to check for NULL! */
        while(*s && isspace(*s))
            ++s;
        if(*s) {
            register char *p = s;
            while(*p)
                ++p;
            do {
                --p;
            } while((p != s) && isspace(*p));
            *(p + 1) = '\0';
        }
    }
    return(s);
}
```

Comment: checking s is not null should be done before the function call. Assume s is a garbage pointer and then how do you gaurantee that this program? Hence bset practice is that S should be checked before the function call and not inside the function call.

Comment: @lakshmanaraj: I said safer...not safe. What if our user is on a non-standard system and wants to call the function like this: mytrim(strdup(x));?

Answer (score 2):

A refinement of another post above.

```
void  strstrip( char *s )
{
  char *start;
  char *end;

  // Exit if param is NULL pointer
  if (s == NULL)
    return;

  // Skip over leading whitespace
  start = s;
  while ((*start) && isspace(*start))
    start++;      

  // Is string just whitespace?
  if (!(*start)) 
  {         
    *s = 0x00; // Truncate entire string
    return;     
  }     

  // Find end of string
  end = start;
  while (*end)         
    end++;     

  // Step back from NUL
  end--;      

  // Step backward until first non-whitespace
  while ((end != start) && isspace(*end))         
    end--;     

  // Chop off trailing whitespace
  *(end + 1) = 0x00;

  // If had leading whitespace, then move entire string back to beginning
  if (s != start)
    memmove(s, start, end-start+1);      

  return; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who would like to see a recursive solution, I offer this:

```
static char* trim_left_ptr(char* str)
{
    if (*str == 0)
    {
        // no more in string. It is an empty string
        return str;
    }

    if (*str == ' ' || *str == '\t')
    {
        // it is space or tab. Try next.
        return trim_left_ptr(str + 1);
    }


    // found left side of string
    return str;
}


static char* trim_right_ptr(char* str)
{
    if (*str == 0)
    {
        // found end of string
        return str;
    }

    // try next (recursion)
    char* ptr = trim_right_ptr( str + 1 );

    // on the return from recursion.
    // ptr == str until a nonspace/nontab is found.
    if (*(ptr - 1) == ' ' || *(ptr - 1) == '\t')
    {
        // is space or tab. Have not yet found right side
        return ptr - 1;
    }

    // found right side of string
    return ptr;
}



char* trim(char* str)
{
    char* L_Ptr = trim_left_ptr(str);
    char* R_Ptr = trim_right_ptr(str);

    // calculate characters to store in new buffer
    _int32 sz = R_Ptr - L_Ptr;

    // allocate buffer
    char* newstr = (char*) malloc(sz + 1);

    // copy trimmed string
    memcpy(newstr, L_Ptr, sz);

    // terminate string
    *(newstr + sz) = 0;

    return newstr;
}
```

Of course, it is not the only possible recursive solution.

Answer (score 2):

Adding yet another answer to an already crowded field, but … I believe with good reason.  Specifically, the (currently accepted) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/352119) by [AlfaZulu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44060/alfazulu) neither strips trailing blanks nor correctly respects the bounds of the arrays.  [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) reports out-of-bounds reads and writes when the source string is an empty string.

Here's sample code with the `stripLeadingAndTrailingSpaces()` function from AlfaZulu's answer verbatim (including the trailing blanks) — with just the `static` added before it to conform to my prejudices. (I use compiler options that prevent the code compiling unless there's either a prototype for the function or the function is static).  There's also a function `str_strip()` which is a fixed version of the function by AlfaZulu.  The test harness puts the two functions to work.  The code assumes a sufficiently POSIX-like environment so that `strdup()` is available to allocate a duplicate copy of a string.

Note that the name `str_strip()` avoids conflict with the reserved names for the standard C library:

> #### 7.31.13 String handling `<string.h>`
>
> 1 Function names that begin with `str`, `mem`, or `wcs` and a lowercase letter may be added
>   to the declarations in the `<string.h>` header.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Code verbatim from answer by AlfaZulu (except for static) — which has problems */
static
void stripLeadingAndTrailingSpaces(char* string){

     assert(string);

     /* First remove leading spaces */

     const char* firstNonSpace = string;

     while(*firstNonSpace != '\0' && isspace(*firstNonSpace))
     {
          ++firstNonSpace;
     }

     size_t len = strlen(firstNonSpace)+1;

     memmove(string, firstNonSpace, len);

     /* Now remove trailing spaces */

     char* endOfString = string + len;

     while(string < endOfString  && isspace(*endOfString))
     {
          --endOfString ;
     }

     *endOfString = '\0';

}

static void str_strip(char *string)
{
    assert(string);
    //printf("-->> %s(): [%s]\n", __func__, string);

    /* First remove leading spaces */
    const char *firstNonSpace = string;

    while (isspace((unsigned char)*firstNonSpace))
        ++firstNonSpace;
    //printf("---- %s(): [%s]\n", __func__, firstNonSpace);

    size_t len = strlen(firstNonSpace) + 1;
    memmove(string, firstNonSpace, len);
    //printf("---- %s(): [%s]\n", __func__, string);

    /* Now remove trailing spaces */
    char *endOfString = string + len - 1;
    //printf("---- %s(): EOS [%s]\n", __func__, endOfString);

    while (string < endOfString && isspace((unsigned char)endOfString[-1]))
        --endOfString;
    *endOfString = '\0';
    //printf("<<-- %s(): [%s]\n", __func__, string);
}

static void chk_stripper(const char *str)
{
    char *copy1 = strdup(str);
    printf("V1 Before: [%s]\n", copy1);
    stripLeadingAndTrailingSpaces(copy1);
    printf("V1 After:  [%s]\n", copy1);
    free(copy1);
    fflush(stdout);

    char *copy2 = strdup(str);
    printf("V2 Before: [%s]\n", copy2);
    str_strip(copy2);
    printf("V2 After:  [%s]\n", copy2);
    free(copy2);
    fflush(stdout);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *str[] =
    {
        "    \t    ABC   DEF    \t  ",
        "    \t                 \t  ",
        " ",
        "",
    };
    enum { NUM_STR = sizeof(str) / sizeof(str[0]) };
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STR; i++)
        chk_stripper(str[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

When run under Valgrind, I get the output:

```
$ valgrind --suppressions=etc/suppressions-macos-10.12.5 -- ./slts59
==26999== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==26999== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==26999== Using Valgrind-3.13.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==26999== Command: ./slts59
==26999== 
V1 Before: [            ABC   DEF         ]
V1 After:  [ABC   DEF         ]
V2 Before: [            ABC   DEF         ]
V2 After:  [ABC   DEF]
V1 Before: [                              ]
V1 After:  []
V2 Before: [                              ]
V2 After:  []
V1 Before: [ ]
V1 After:  []
V2 Before: [ ]
V2 After:  []
==26999== Invalid read of size 1
==26999==    at 0x100000B81: stripLeadingAndTrailingSpaces (slts59.c:28)
==26999==    by 0x100000CB0: chk_stripper (slts59.c:67)
==26999==    by 0x100000DA2: main (slts59.c:91)
==26999==  Address 0x100b7df01 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==26999==    at 0x100096861: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:302)
==26999==    by 0x1002DC938: strdup (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==26999==    by 0x100000C88: chk_stripper (slts59.c:65)
==26999==    by 0x100000DA2: main (slts59.c:91)
==26999== 
==26999== Invalid write of size 1
==26999==    at 0x100000B96: stripLeadingAndTrailingSpaces (slts59.c:33)
==26999==    by 0x100000CB0: chk_stripper (slts59.c:67)
==26999==    by 0x100000DA2: main (slts59.c:91)
==26999==  Address 0x100b7df01 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==26999==    at 0x100096861: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:302)
==26999==    by 0x1002DC938: strdup (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==26999==    by 0x100000C88: chk_stripper (slts59.c:65)
==26999==    by 0x100000DA2: main (slts59.c:91)
==26999== 
V1 Before: []
V1 After:  []
V2 Before: []
V2 After:  []
==26999== 
==26999== HEAP SUMMARY:
==26999==     in use at exit: 34,572 bytes in 162 blocks
==26999==   total heap usage: 186 allocs, 24 frees, 40,826 bytes allocated
==26999== 
==26999== LEAK SUMMARY:
==26999==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26999==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26999==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26999==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26999==         suppressed: 34,572 bytes in 162 blocks
==26999== 
==26999== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==26999== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
$
```

The `str_strip()` function shown is working correctly.  It features a more or less minimal set of changes necessary to get `stripLeadingAndTrailingSpaces()` to work cleanly (plus commented out debug code used during the checking process — that could go now).

I observe that although it has slightly different semantics, the Linux-based `strstrip()` function from [Tuminoid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40657/tuminoid)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/352109/15168) is also clean — no memory access errors, and it removes trailing blanks (without moving the portion of the string between the first and last non-blank characters).

Comment: I'd think `*firstNonSpace != '\0' &&` is unnecessary in `while(*firstNonSpace != '\0' && isspace(*firstNonSpace))`.  Style? Concern `isspace(0)` might be true?

Comment: Yes agree about "only so many issues one can face at a given time"

Comment: @chux: actually, the code you're complaining about is copied from another answer — and my fixed code is later in my answer.  I'm critiquing the code — and my fixed code already applies the changes you suggested.  Please apply your observations to the original answer rather than mine.  I'm about to undo the changes, but add comments to make it clearer that this is code that's not mine and is error prone.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = strlen(s) - 1;
while (isspace(s[i]))
    s[i--] = '\0';
while (isspace(*s))
    s++;
```

That should take care of the problem as long as you don't care about mangling up the string like crazy and if you don't care about memory leaks!

Comment: what heppens if s contains only spaces? ;-)

Comment: This will under run if s is zero lenth or contains only spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it in-place; stripping whitespace can never cause the string to grow. You might be able to do it without first checking the length of the string, but doing so might be needlessly "clever". You should look into the `memmove()` function, in addition to the ones @Norman Ramsey mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Linux/Windows and have the library glib linked into your program, you can use the the routine [`g_strstrip()`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/2.16/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strstrip).

Answer (score 1):

```
char *strip(char *string)
{
    char *start = string;
    while(isblank(*start)) start++;
    int end = strlen(start);
    if(start != string) {
        memmove(string, start, end);
        string[end] = '\0';
    }
    while(isblank(*(string+end-1))) end--;
    string[end] = '\0';
    return string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Correted algorithm from fpsgamer (also ISO C90 valid):

```
void trimWhitespace(char *string) {
    const char* firstNonSpace = string;
    char* endOfString;
    size_t len;

    if (string[0] == '\0') {
        return;
    }

    /* First remove leading spaces */
    while(*firstNonSpace != '\0' && isspace(*firstNonSpace)) {
        ++firstNonSpace;
    }
    len = strlen(firstNonSpace) + 1;
    memmove(string, firstNonSpace, len);

    /* Now remove trailing spaces */
    endOfString = string + len;

    while(string < endOfString && (isspace(*endOfString) || *endOfString == '\0')) {
        --endOfString ;
    }

    *(endOfString + 1) = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation of how this corrects or improves on his answer? (Please include the explanation in the answer rather than replying in a comment)

Answer (score 1):

for trailing white spaces use strtok. set the delimiter = " " and when it runs it discards the delimiter byte and returns char * to the token

```
char *x;
char *y = "somestring "; 

x = strtok(y," ");
```

result x = pointer to "somestring" not "somestring "

Comment: strtok does not work if the trimmed string contains whitespace (then it cuts off the rest of the string). Try with "somestring with spaces   " then you'll still get "somestring" and not the correct "somestring with spaces".

Comment: The purpose of `strtok()` is not _to remove any character_ and it is a "costly" operation for removing a trailing white space. May cause isses when the string contains a white-space, and requires the programmer to make 100% sure that the string does not have any mediate white-space characters in it.

Answer (score 1):

Edit : Updated the code based on the latest version of [zString library](https://github.com/fnoyanisi/zString).

This code relies on no libraries, only pointer arithmetic and integers.
There are three functions : trim, lef-trim and right-trim. (I should add all these functions in to [zString library](https://github.com/fnoyanisi/zString) :) )

- `char *zstring_trim(char *s)` removes leading and trailing white-spaces
- `char *zstring_ltrim(char *s)` removes leading whites-spaces
- `char *zstring_ltrim(char *s)` removes trailing whites-spaces

All these functions modify the original character string

```
/* trim */
char *zstring_trim(char *str){
    char *src=str;  /* save the original pointer */
    char *dst=str;  /* result */
    char c;
    int is_space=0;
    int in_word=0;  /* word boundary logical check */
    int index=0;    /* index of the last non-space char*/

    /* validate input */
    if (!str)
        return str;

    while ((c=*src)){
        is_space=0;

        if (c=='\t' || c=='\v' || c=='\f' || c=='\n' || c=='\r' || c==' ')
            is_space=1;

        if(is_space == 0){
         /* Found a word */
            in_word = 1;
            *dst++ = *src++;  /* make the assignment first
                               * then increment
                               */
        } else if (is_space==1 && in_word==0) {
         /* Already going through a series of white-spaces */
            in_word=0;
            ++src;
        } else if (is_space==1 && in_word==1) {
         /* End of a word, dont mind copy white spaces here */
            in_word=0;
            *dst++ = *src++;
            index = (dst-str)-1; /* location of the last char */
        }
    }

    /* terminate the string */
    *(str+index)='\0';

    return str;
}

/* right trim */
char *zstring_rtrim(char *str){
    char *src=str;  /* save the original pointer */
    char *dst=str;  /* result */
    char c;
    int is_space=0;
    int index=0;    /* index of the last non-space char */

    /* validate input */
    if (!str)
        return str;

    /* copy the string */
    while(*src){
        *dst++ = *src++;
        c = *src;

        if (c=='\t' || c=='\v' || c=='\f' || c=='\n' || c=='\r' || c==' ')
            is_space=1;
        else
            is_space=0;

        if (is_space==0 && *src)
            index = (src-str)+1;
    }

    /* terminate the string */
    *(str+index)='\0';

    return str;
}

/* left trim */
char *zstring_ltrim(char *str){
    char *src=str;  /* save the original pointer */
    char *dst=str;  /* result */
    char c;
    int index=0;    /* index of the first non-space char */

    /* validate input */
    if (!str)
        return str;

    /* skip leading white-spaces */
    while((c=*src)){ 
        if (c=='\t' || c=='\v' || c=='\f' || c=='\n' || c=='\r' || c==' '){
            ++src;
            ++index;
        } else
            break;
    }

    /* copy rest of the string */
    while(*src)
        *dst++ = *src++;

    /* terminate the string */
    *(src-index)='\0';

    return str;
}
```