# I want to read from file in c line by line and check each line if it is an integer

Tags: c, file

how can i read from file line by line and check each line if it is an integer?

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("users.txt", "r");


while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &IDRead)!=EOF)
{
  enter code here
}

fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Well, enter some code there ...

Comment: You could do with checking the return value from `fopen`

Comment: Also check the return value from fscanf()

Comment: use [`fgets`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) and [`isdigit`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isdigit)

Comment: Oh btw, the code that's already there doesn't meet your spec. Still, you should show complete code, see [mcve]

Comment: if you're dealing with the file "line by line", shouldn't you read the file in "line by "line" with say `fgets`?

Comment: how can i read from file line by line --> `fgets()`.  ... and check each line if it is an integer?  --> `strtol()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read a line and [`isdigit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) to check if each character in the string is a number.

First we can make an `isnumber()` function that checks if each character in a string is a number. To handle negative numbers we can check that the first character is either a digit or '-'.

```
bool isnumber(char* str) {
    int len = strlen(str);
    if (len <= 0) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check if first char is negative sign or digit
    if (str[0] != '-' && !isidigit(str[0])) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check that all remaining chars are digits
    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        if (!isdigit(str[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Our `isnumber()` function assumes the string has no leading or trailing white space, and a string retrieved from `fgets()` may have both. We'll need a function that strips whitespace from both ends of a string. You can read about how to do so in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/122721/9614249).

Now we can use our `isnumber()` function inside of a while loop to check each line in a file with `fgets()`.

```
FILE *fp = fopen("users.txt", "r");
if(!fp) {
    perror("Failed to open file");
    return -1;
}

const int MAX = 256;
char line[MAX];
while (fgets(line, MAX, fp) != NULL) {
    stripLeadingAndTrailingSpaces(line);
    printf("%s\t", line);

    if (isnumber(line)) {
        printf("is a number\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("is not a number\n");
    }
}

fclose(fp);
```

Comment: `isnumber()`  returns false due to `'\n'`.  Also returns false due to leading white-space or `'+'`.

Comment: Note: The [referenced answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/352119/9614249) to strip whitespace has technical UB and inefficiencies as well as 6 down-votes.